# Wrong data in power apps when clicking from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Dears,

I am facing issue with customized form of power apps integrated in SharePoint.

when I view the list of SharePoint the data shows different and when I click on one item from the list it always shows the first record.

In the ITEM I am using the below formula.

If(IsBlank(SharePointIntegration.Selected) || IsEmpty(SharePointIntegration.Selected),First([@'testlist']),SharePointIntegration.Selected)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can add some screenshot for references and some details and maybe any code.

Comment: What is the formula used in "item" property of form control in power apps? Might be you are getting blank "SharePointIntegration" object hence it is always showing first item.

Comment: Dear @GaneshSanap, yes you are right, can I know why I am not getting the selected object in SharePointIntegaration